# How to manage scheduled tasks of different java projects from a central project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

Suppose I have some scheduled jobs in some spring-boot projects. I want to manage all those schedulers from a central project. By managing i mean start and stop the execution, change interval of scheduled tasks. How can I do it?

Comment: what do you mean by managing? which operations you want to perform on scheduled tasks? stopping execution?

Comment: Yes, starting and stopping the execution. I want to set and update the scheduler interval also.